# Haskell - a very simple function

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to understand the following function:

```
q1 :: [Int]  -> Int
q1 []                    = 0
q1 [x]                   = x
q1 (x:_:xs)              = max x (q1 xs)
```

When inputting this: q1 (map abs [-1,-6,-5,7]), it gets me 5. Can someone walk me through why this happens? I understand how map functions, but the pattern matching (x:_xs) is a bit confusing. Thanks!

Comment: The pattern `x:_:xs` matches a list with at least two elements; the first element is named `x`, the second element is discarded, and the rest of the list (all but first two elements) is named `xs`. Does this clarify what this pattern means?

Comment: Yeah, that explains it. Feel stupid now since I missed that the second one is discarded... Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A list in Haskell is - at least conceptually - a *linked list*. there are two possibilities:

- an empty list `[]`; or
- a "cons" `(x:xs)` where `x` is the *head* (first item), and `xs` the *tail* (the rest of the list).

Haskell also uses *syntactical sugar*. For instance `[1]` is behind the curtains translated to `(1:[])`, and `[1,4,2,5]` to `(1:(4:(2:(5:[]))))`.

Why is this important? We first will try to understand the `q1` function. If we look at the type, we see that `q1` takes as input a list of `Int`s, and returns an `Int`. It is defined recursively as:

```
q1 :: [Int]  -> Int
q1 [] = 0
q1 [x] = x
q1 (x:_:xs) = max x (q1 xs)
```

This means that `q1` for an empty list is zero (`0`); that the `q1` for a list with one element `x` is `x`. For a list with *two* or more elements is the `maximum` of the first item of that list `x`, and *tail of the tail* of that list. This is because we pattern match with `(x:_:xs)` which is short for `(x:(_:xs))`. The underscore basically means "*don't care*". So the list should be a *cons* where the tail is a *cons* as well, and we are interested in the head of the list `x`, and the tail of the tail of the list `xs`.

If we reason about this, we thus find out that `q1` returns the *maximum* of the elements at *odd indices* (so the first, third, fifth, etc. element). In case the list has an *even* length, we also calculate the maximum with zero (so in case the all elements at odd indices are negative, the function will return zero, but this *only* in the case we have a list of *even* length).

Now if wel call it with `q1 (map abs [-1,-6,-5,7])`, it thus means that we will call `q1` on the *result* of `map abs` on `[-1, -6, -5, 7]`. `map abs` constructs a list where `abs` is applied to all elements of the list (although it is applied lazily). So after the `map abs [-1, -6, -5, 7]`, we obtain the list `[1, 6, 5, 7]`. Now the elements at the odd indices are `1` and `5`. So `q1` will calculate the maximum of these elements and zero (since the length of the list is four, which is even). And *max(0, 1, 5)* is *5*.

Personally, especially the fact that we also consider zero but only in case the list has an *even* length, is very "*unstable*". It can result in bugs that are hard to understand, since it can be the result of a detail of the function. We can for instance calculate the maximum with zero, regardless of the length of the list:

```
q2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
q2 [] = 0
q2 [x] = max 0 x
q2 (x:_:xs) = max x (q2 xs)
```

Or we can decide to not use zero at all, and not define maximum over an empty list, like for instance:

```
q3 :: Ord a => [a] -> a
q3 [x] = x
q3 [x,_] = x
q3 (x:_:xs) = max x (q3 xs)
```

Comment: Damn this was a very good a thorough answer! I had not understood that we would go though odd indices before asking but now it makes perfect sense why I get 5! Much obliged for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: ... and then you say that `q3 . map abs` is [a list homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%E2%80%93Meertens_formalism#The_homomorphism_lemma_and_its_applications_to_parallel_implementations) over [`chunksOf 2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf)'ed lists, and so is equivalent to `maximum . (0:) . map (abs . head) . chunksOf 2` or something.

Comment: @WillNess: sure, but the last section is more meant as a comment on the fact that `q` is simply not a good function, not meant to go in much design of a better function, only a brief overview of two options in Layman's terms :)

Comment: BTW the `0` thing means that `q1` expects (nay demands) its arguments in a list to all be non-negative, that this is an essential part of its interface (*not* captured by its type). Goes well with the `map abs`, too.

Comment: @WillNess: exactly and the fact that it is not constrained by the type nor that it performs an `abs` itself, nor that it always uses zero makes it completely horrible function.

Comment: yes, the old efficiency/correctness trade-off. the programmer thinks, "if I already have only the non-zero numbers in my list I could skip calling the `(abs <$>)` on it." this is a real problem BTW, sometimes the ensuring of correctness is a very heavy calculation, not to be taken lightly (the repeating of it, I mean).